# Create an empty HTML file using Python?

Tags: python, html, operating-system

I need to create an empty html file using python. I'm new to OS module and i can't find any examples of doing it.

**How can I create an empty html file using python?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need the `os` module; just open a file for writing and close it:

```
with open('index.html', 'w'):
    pass
```

You might want to write nothing to it explicitly as other developers may be confused if you just open a file without doing anything with it:

```
with open('index.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write('')
```

Comment: When did you start answering python questions?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I answer questions when I feel like it. vOv I just happened to see this one floating around.

Comment: Glad to have you here man! :D

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of creating an empty text file with the .html extension.

You can do that in Python with:

```
file = open('emptyfile.html', 'w')  
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('example.html', 'w') as f:
    # you can do something with f
    pass
```